# Both receive and send data via TCP on node-red

Tags: node-red

before beginning with node-red I thought my little application to be easy. I want to interact with a device via TCP. The device will send me data on this connection, at the same time I want to be able to send commands through the same connection. These commands will be answered by the device through the same connection.

Now in node-red, I did not come across a node, which would me enable to do this.

I have a TCP-Input, TCP-Output and TCP-Request node. All of them don't serve my purpose. TCP-Input and TCP-Output don't seem to work on the same address and port. The option "Reply to TCP" within the TCP-Output node does not seem to have any effect.

Am I breaking with basic principles of node-red with this type of connection or is there a simple way around this.

In the end I just want an open TCP socket connection allowing me to send and receive data.

Hope someone has a suggestion how to solve my problem.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am in the same boat!

Answer (score 2):

The TCP out node needs a specific set of data to work. Namely the `msg._​session` property. That is how it identifies which TCP session to send to since a TCP in node could be connected to by many clients.

So set up the in node first, check the `_session` property details and add that to the out node.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at function , there is TCP Request node.

It's what you need.
Hope that's help